# ionic grid force row to be visible

Tags: ionic-framework

I've got a simple `ion-grid` with about 12 rows in it inside in `ion-scroll`.

```
<ion-scroll style="height: 30vh;" scrollY="true">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of allItems; let si = index" [style.background-color]="si === selectedRow ? '#cccccc' : ''">
      <ion-col col-2>{{item.text}}</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-scroll>
```

I've got some buttons with a callback that sets `selectedRow`. Through the magic of data binding when I click a button the right row gets highlighted (yay).

**What I want is to force the `ion-scroll` to scroll the highlighted row into view.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.

In the html template give the row an id:

`<div ion-row *ngFor="let row of all_data_rows; let idx= index"  id="{{'row_' + idx}}">`

Then in the .ts where i programmatically set the row I want visible:

```
let row = document.getElementById("row_" + this.selectedRow)
row.scrollIntoView()
```

It ensures the row selected is at the top of the scroll viewport which is probably a bit more scrolling than I wanted but it works. Passing `false` to `scrollIntoView()` tries to put the row at the bottom of the viewport which looks a lot better in my case since it causes less scrolling.